# elasticsearch index mapping is Long but saved String type

Tags: elasticsearch, types

elasticsearch version is 6.8.5

1 - elasticsearch index mapping is long, but saved data have string type, why?

2 - I only can search data by num, but cannot search by string, how can I use string type to search data

here is my mapping, arr_value type is long:

```
{
"ticket_instance":{
    "properties":{
        "ticket_definition_id":{
            "index":"not_analyzed",
            "type":"string"
        },
        "variable":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
                "arr_value":{
                    "type":"long"
                },
                "create_time":{
                    "type":"long"
                },
                "last_updated_time":{
                    "type":"long"
                }
            }
        },
        "ticket_definition_key":{
            "index":"not_analyzed",
            "type":"string"
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is my exception search:

```
{
"query":{

    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {
                "terms":{
                    "ticket_definition_key":[
                        "e4165ca3-f918-4e03-b0ba-6f2e1d28d70c"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "nested":{
                    "query":{
                        "bool":{

                            "must":[


                                {
                                    "term":{
                                        "variable.arr_value":{
                                            "value":"A-1-name"
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
                            ]

                        }
                    },
                    "path":"variable",
                    "score_mode":"none"
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative":true
    }
},
"size":10
```

}

the search worked when I changed the arr_value from "A-1-name" to "123".
NumberFormatException occured when used "A-1-name"

Comment: can you share *entire mapping* of your index ? also your search query

Comment: the entire mapping is above..